# Slide in animation with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css-animations

I'm trying to accomplish a slide-in effect like the one on [this site](http://acme-world.com/).

I found a a good [tutorial here](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/), but I still need help with a couple of things. I have 9 sections following the same structure and logic. I will put only three on my snippet.

What I need its a way to set the space between sections at top:-28px after the animation it's over but still far enough before animation so they can be animated.

So far I animated the full section, but I would like to edit the JS and CSS in order to animate individually the picture, header and text (to feel more like in the example page).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
(function($) {

  /**
   * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
   *
   * @author Sam Sehnert
   * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
   *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
   *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
   */

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
    
      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
    
    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };
    
})(jQuery);



 var win = $(window);




 var allMods = $(".full-module-scroll");




allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible"); 
  } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {
  
  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
  });
  
});
var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".full-module-scroll");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible"); 
  } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {
  
  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
  });
  
});

});
```

```css
/*Animation*/
/*The important part*/
@import "compass/css3";

.full-module-scroll{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 483px;
 }
.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px); /*I would like to understand this better*/
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
 }

.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
 }

@keyframes come-in {
  to { transform: translateY(0); }
 }




/*Styles*/
 #all-apps-container{
   display: inline-block; 
   margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
.apps-text-container{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 60%; 
  }  
.apps-green-header{
    font-size: 30pt;
    color: #00A8A1;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
.apps-description {
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 28pt;
    color: #666666;
  }
.apps-align-right{
   text-align: right;
   }
.apps-align-left{
   text-align: left;
   }
#sicem-web-container{
   position:relative;
   margin-top: 50px; 
  }
#sicem-img-container {
   background-image : url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze48o.png);
   background-repeat : no-repeat;
   position : relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 483px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right; 
  }
#sicem-description{
   width: 581px;
   float: right;  
  }
#movil-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
#movil-img-container {
   background-image : url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sccj4.png);
   background-repeat : no-repeat;
   position : relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 483px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left; 
  }
#movil-description{
    width: 513px;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all-apps-container">

<div id="sicem-web-container" class="full-module-scroll">
 <div class="apps-text-container apps-align-right">
   <div class="apps-green-header"> Header</div>
   <div class="apps-description" id="sicem-description"> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</div>
 </div>

  <div id="sicem-img-container">  </div>
<div>


<div id="movil-container" class="full-module-scroll">
 <div id="movil-img-container"> </div>  
   <div class="apps-text-container apps-align-left">
    <div class="apps-green-header"> A nother header</div>
    <div class="apps-description" id="movil-description"> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div id="all-apps-container">

<div id="sicem-web-container" class="full-module-scroll">
 <div class="apps-text-container apps-align-right">
   <div class="apps-green-header"> Header</div>
   <div class="apps-description" id="sicem-description"> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</div>
 </div>

  <div id="sicem-img-container">  </div>
<div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following css to all the elements you want to move:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Then you just have to change the css of the elements via javascript like:

```
document.getElementById(yourelementid).style=" width:100px; " //<-- Whatever you want
```

Or you add the sice you want to have in your original css file and just change the style in html. Then you just delete the style from html like this:

```
css: 
#yourdiv { width:100px; }

HTML: <div id="yourdiv" style="width:0px;"></div>

JavaScript:  document.getElementById(yourdiv).style="" // clear html style
```

Maybe this will give you the effect